# Average LOC per commit (github)

Tags: git, version-control, github

This is a completely subjective question directed towards Github users...

What is your average number of lines-of-code change per commit?

I find myself to be committing after every 50 lines of code-change, and I think its a little paradiod :) Wondering what kind of commit behavior other users exhibit..

If anyone has any hard stats on the average LOC change per commit across any collection of VCS sites, that would be welcome also

Comment: What matters more is probably finishing a feature or fixing a bug, not number of lines. This question is out of scope of Stackoverflow anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer make as small commits, as possible.
But it's not about line counts per commit.
General rule: one bug/feature - one commit.
It's good for collaboration and future maintenance of code.